# Declare a Class Generically

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a windows service that collect data from a client's printer software.

The Windows Service has a list of classes per Printer Software package:

  clsSoftwareA

  clsSoftwareB

Although each class has the same functions, each function inside the class does something complete to get a standard list of data from the different systems.

So when the service starts up, it will determine the printer system and the class required.

```
Dim clsPrinter As Object
Dim strPSClassName As String

strPSClassName = GetPrinterClass(ClientID) 'Get ClassName for the Client

clsPrinter = CreateObject(strPSClassName)
```

I need to somehow have Object that I can assign to a specific class based on the name of the class.

Comment: >I need to somehow have Object that I can assign to a specific class based on the name of the class. 
I dont really understand what precisely you mean by this?

Comment: if you want to know what class it is that is created, perhaps you could try something like `if TypeOf ObjectName Is clsSoftware A Then`?

Comment: @AConfusedSimpleton I dont need to to know the type of object ... I need to to declare the object based on certain class. In my example clsPrinter need to set as either clsSoftwareA or clsSoftwareB based on the type of software the client uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have two classes (and will only ever have two classes), then I'd recommend to go with Louis's answer.  However, if you have more, or you expect to need to add more later, a reflection-based factory doesn't need any extra coding for additional object types, and it only requires a bit of boilerplate coding on your creatable objects.

You need to start with the interface or base class type that the individual types will implement.

```
Interface IFactoryObject
    '...
End Interface
```

You will also need a convention for how the objects will say what they can handle.  For this example, I will assume:

```
Public Shared Function GetObjectName As String
```

For this example, I'll assume that the objects are just being created with their constructor, but you could also have a self-create method exposed by convention.

Setting up the factory involves scanning one or more assemblies for conforming types, e.g.

```
Private Shared _ctors As New Dictionary(Of String, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo)

Public Shared Sub InitializeFactory(ByVal assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly)
    For Each thisType In assembly.GetTypes()
        If GetType(IFactoryObject).IsAssignableFrom(thisType) Then
            Dim typeMethodInfo = thisType.GetMethod("GetObjectName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
            'Validation that typeMethodInfo is not Nothing, has the right argument type(s), and has the right return type left as an exercise for the reader
            Dim typeDelegate = DirectCast(typeMethodInfo.CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of String))), Func(Of String))
            Dim typeName = typeDelegate.Invoke()
            Dim ctor = thisType.GetConstructor({})

            _ctors.Add(typeName, ctor)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then, the actual runtime creation works like this:

```
Public Shared Function CreateFactoryObject(ByVal objectName As String) As IFactoryObject
    Dim createdObject As Object = _ctors(objectName).Invoke({})
    Return CType(createdObject, IFactoryObject)
End Function
```

Note that this isn't the fastest code because of how it uses reflection.  Jon Skeet talked about converting `MethodInfo` to delegate instances back in 2008: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/

Comment: As an aside, code above assumes that you want to call a parameterless ctor.  There are various strategies that you might pursue if you were to desire to use a ctor which would take one or more arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write out your conditions and when the condition is met (for the name of the current device), instantiate your object there.

```
string MyDeviceName;
MyDeviceName = "whatever you find the current device to be";

switch (MyDeviceName)
{
  case "Printer A":
  //Do something here
  break;

  case "Printer B":
  //Do something else here
  break;

  default:
  break;

}
```

Comment: Seems like this is the only way. Would be great if there was a more dynamic way.